# Checking if bit is 1 at a certain position

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I have a 4-bit number representation in JavaScript, that represent the 4 times of the day (morning, afternoon, evening, night).

So lets say I have the number 13 (1101) in decimal, it represent that some action has to be done in the night, evening and morning (not afternoon, as the 2nd bit is 0).

What I did so far is get the 4-bit digit that represents the day (1000 is night, 0100 is evening, 0010 is afternoon, 0001 is morning), and what I want to do is create a function that compares the 2 numbers, and returns true if the bit at certain position is equal to one.

I am aware of bitwise operators, but I tried to use them but still no luck.

Comment: `(x & (1<<bit_pos)) != 0`

Comment: `!!(x & (1<<bit_pos))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, bit-wise. You can use a simple bit-mask test.

```
var PERIODS_OF_DAY = {
  MORNING: 1, AFTERNOON: 2, EVENING: 4, NIGHT: 8
};

var isPeriodOfDay = function(number, period) {
  return !!(number & period);
};
```

Testing the number `13`:

```
for (period in PERIODS_OF_DAY) {
    if(PERIODS_OF_DAY.hasOwnProperty(period)) {
        console.log(period + ":", isPeriodOfDay(13, PERIODS_OF_DAY[period]));
    }
}
```

```
MORNING: true
AFTERNOON: false
EVENING: true
NIGHT: true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTimes (value, time) {
    var times = ["morning", "afternoon", "evening", "night"];

    if (time) {
        return !(~value & 1 << times.indexOf(time));
    }

    return times.filter(function(time, i) { return !(~value & 1 << i); });
}

console.log(getTimes(13, "afternoon")); // false
console.log(getTimes(13)); // ["morning", "evening", "night]
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wrbbc/4/)